# Sqlite: Are SQLITE_ENABLE_STAT3 tables created when upgrading?

Tags: sqlite

Consider an SQLite database created with the [SQLITE_ENABLE_STAT2](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_stat2) flag set. After updating my software, the new SQLite version seems to use another flag; [SQLITE_ENABLE_STAT3](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_stat3).

Will these `stat3` optimizations be available when opening and old database created with `stat2`? Or is it perhaps necessary to run the [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ANALYZE` command *is* necessary.